# refresh page using jQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

How do I refresh the page(from overlay) using jQuery with Fade In effect?

I have a div tag on the page and I open that like overlay using jQuery. Once I click "Ok" or "Cancel" on that overlay I need to refresh the page(to reload the data) closing the overlay with Fade In/Fade Out effect.

Ajax update panel is doing partial post back and user doesn't see the page is getting refreshed.  I wanted to do same thing using jQuery with Fade In/Fade Out effect.

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing something like this.

```
$( "body").fadeOut( function(){
       location.reload(true); 
       setTimeout( function(){
           $(body).fadeIn();
       }, 5000);
 });
```

While was writing found a better way:

```
$( "body").fadeOut( 
           function(){
              location.reload(true);
              $( document).ready( function(){$(body).fadeIn();}); 
           });
```

Answer (score 3):

To refresh the entire page, you can use:

```
window.location = window.location;
```

Comment: I guess the question wasn't about how simply refresh the entire page. Because it could be done with location.reload(true).